# Understanding ItemsSource and DataContext in a DataGrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

*UPDATE: See the bottom of this question for what I did to solve the problem.*

I'm trying to understand how the `ItemsSource` and `DataContext` properties work in a Silverlight Toolkit `DataGrid`.  I'm currently working with dummy data and trying to get the data in the `DataGrid` to update when the value of a combo box changes.

My MainPage.xaml.vb file currently looks like this:

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits UserControl

Private IssueSummaryList As List(Of IssueSummary)    

Public Sub New()
    GetDummyIssueSummary("Day")
    InitializeComponent()
    dgIssueSummary.ItemsSource = IssueSummaryList
    'dgIssueSummary.DataContext = IssueSummaryList        '
End Sub

Private Sub GetDummyIssueSummary(ByVal timeInterval As String)
    Dim lst As New List(Of IssueSummary)()
    'Generate dummy data for lst '
    IssueSummaryList = lst
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    Dim cboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim cboBoxItem As ComboBoxItem = CType(cboBox.SelectedValue, ComboBoxItem)
    GetDummyIssueSummary(cboBoxItem.Content.ToString())
End Sub

End Class
```

My XAML currently looks this for the `DataGrid`:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgIssueSummary" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProblemType}" Header="Problem Type"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count}" Header="Count"/>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

The problem is that if I set the value of the `ItemsSource` property of the data grid equal to `IssueSummaryList`, it will display the data when it loads, but it won't update when the underlying `IssueSummaryList` collection changes.  If I set the `DataContext` of the grid to be `IssueSummaryList`, no data will be displayed when it renders.

I must not understand how `ItemsSource` and `DataContext` are supposed to function, because I expect one of those properties to "just work" when I assign a `List` object to them.  What do I need to understand and change in my code so that as data changes in the `List`, the data in the grid is updated?

---

Here's what I did to solve the problem:

- First, I changed `IssueSummaryList` to be of type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`.  The `ObservableCollection` object raises events when items are added or removed from the collection, telling the datagrid to refresh its view.
- Next, I changed the `GetDummyIssueSummary()` method to modify `IssueSummaryList` directly instead of setting it to a new instance of a `List` or `ObservableCollection`.

These two changes allowed the data grid to refresh when the combo box changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataContext` is used for binding dependency property values to another source. `ItemsSource` is used for an `ItemsControl` to provide a list of objects to display.

If all you want to do is to be able to set this list in your code and not in XAML or through a data binding expression, then setting `DataContext` is not required (nor will it do anything for you if you do set it). It's also worth noting that the data context used for binding will check the control parent recursively until it finds a non-null value. In other words, if your `DataContext` is `null`, then it will check the control's parent, then its parent, and so on until it finds a non-null value to use (or it reaches the end of the chain).

When you say that it won't update when the underlying list changes, what sort of change are you referring to? If you're speaking of adding and removing items, then what type of collection are you using? In order for this to work, the type needs to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` or `IBindingList`. `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` as is a common candidate for this sort of thing.

If you're saying that changes to the *contents* of the list (meaning property changes to items that are in the list, not changes to the list itself) are not reflected, then you'll need to ensure that your objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Clarification, use INotifyPropertyChanged if the changes to the contents of already displayed items in the list are not reflected.

Comment: @Danny: That is what I meant, though I'll admit that it wasn't entirely clear. I was trying to differentiate between changes *to the list* (adding, removing, reordering, etc.) and changes *to its items* (property changes). I'll try to edit to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed `IssueSummaryList` to be an `ObservableCollection` and modified `GetDummyIssueSummary()` accordingly, but the grid still isn't updating when the `IssueSummaryList` gets reset.  I have `dgIssueSummary.ItemsSource` set it my constructor still, but it doesn't seem to "stick."

Comment: @Ben: `IssueSummaryList` is an instance variable. While you're setting `ItemsSource = IssueSummaryList` in the constructor, subsequent changes to `IssueSummaryList` won't be reflected automatically in the grid (just like any other variable). You'll need to set the `ItemsSource` property again.

Comment: That makes sense.  I modified my `GetDummyIssueSummary()` method to modify `IssueSummaryList` directly instead of setting it to a new instance of `ObservableCollection`, and that made it work correctly.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`ItemsSource` is where the items come from, `DataContext` is where the bindings are relative to.

E.g.

If `ItemsSource` is set via code, then the `DataContext` is irrelevant to `ItemsSource`.

If `ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"`, then `ItemsSource` is connected to where ever data context is set to + `.MyList`.

If `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`, then `ItemsSource` is connected to where ever data context is set to.